# Changing | manipulating json elements or appending namespace prefixes to json elements

Tags: json, namespaces, badgerfish

thank you in advanced.
I need some help manipulating the following:

- Ultimately, I really need the simplest way to update the parent json element (or any json element) from the code I have. Is there a way to take my var prime output and change startNode into tns:startNode?

Here's my code

```
var vPrefix = "tns";
var vNamespace = "http://somenamespace.com";
var badgerfish = function(text) {
    return {
        "$": text
    };
};
var prime = {};
prime.startNode = {};

prime.startNode['@xmlns'] = {"tns": vNamespace};

prime.startNode.test1 = badgerfish("testValue1");
prime.startNode.test2 = badgerfish("testValue2");
prime.startNode.test3 = {};
prime.startNode.test3.subtest1 = badgerfish("subtestValue1");
var node = JSON.stringify(prime);
session.output.write(node);
```

which outputs the following:

```
{
  "startNode": {
    "@xmlns": {
      "tns": "http:\/\/somenamespace.com"
    },
    "test1": {
      "$": "testValue1"
    },
    "test2": {
      "$": "testValue2"
    },
    "test3": {
      "subtest1": {
        "$": "subtestValue1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and all I'm trying to accomplish is the following (difference is only the tns prefix on startNode):

```
{
  "tns:startNode": {
    "@xmlns": {
      "tns": "http:\/\/somenamespace.com"
    },
    "test1": {
      "$": "testValue1"
    },
    "test2": {
      "$": "testValue2"
    },
    "test3": {
      "subtest1": {
        "$": "subtestValue1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's always this:

`prime = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(prime).replace(/startNode/g, 'tns:startNode') );`

This will give you back a valid JSON object, but you may not even need `parse` given you want to output a string representation of the JSON. I am not sure if this is more or less performant than traversing the JSON to update the key.

Comment: wow, ... I'm an idiot. thank you so much Eric. That was it... a big duh =)